# Why does awaiting Promise.resolve(v) give you v but not awaiting gives you a promise?

Tags: angular, promise, async-await

When I do this:

```
const p = Promise.resolve(‘hello world’);
console.log(p);
```

I get this for output:

```
ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: "hello world"}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: "hello world"
__proto__: Object
```

But if I do this:

```
const p = await Promise.resolve(‘hello world’);
```

I get this for output:

```
hello world
```

Why is it that when I don’t await the Promise.resolve(…), p is a promise, but when I do, p is the value the promise resolves to?

I ask because from what I understand, Promise.resolve(…) is not asynchronous, which means it resolves right away. Therefore, shouldn’t p just be the value ‘hello world’ in both cases? What is await awaiting if the promise is already resolved? To put it another way: what happens between the time a promise is resolved and the time it give you the value resolved to? And what triggers that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `Promise.resolve(val)` is specifically designed to return a Promise object.  That's what it is designed to do.  So, when you do:

```
const p = Promise.resolve('hello world');
console.log(p);
```

The variable `p` contains exactly what `Promise.resolve()` is designed to return, a promise object.

That promise object happens to already be resolved internally, but when you examine the return value, what you see is the Promise object.

As with ALL promise objects, if you want the resolved value out of the promise object, you have to use `.then()` or `await` to get access to the value.  The promise returned from `Promise.resolve()` is no different in that regard than any other promise.

```
const p = Promise.resolve('hello world');
console.log(p);           // shows you the promise object

p.then(val => {
    console.log(val);     // 'hello world'
});

// or this
console.log(await p);     // 'hello world'
```

> Why is it that when I don’t await the Promise.resolve(…), p is a promise, but when I do, p is the value the promise resolves to?

Because `Promise.resolve()` returns a promise object, always and `await p` gets you the value from that promise object.

> I ask because from what I understand, Promise.resolve(…) is not asynchronous, which means it resolves right away. Therefore, shouldn’t p just be the value ‘hello world’ in both cases? What is await awaiting if the promise is already resolved? To put it another way: what happens between the time a promise is resolved and the time it give you the value resolved to? And what triggers that?

You use `Promise.resolve()` when what you WANT is a promise object that is already in the resolved state.  If you just want a value, you don't use `Promise.resolve()` at all.  So, there is generally no point in code like this:

```
const val = await Promise.resolve('hello world');
```

You may as well just do this:

```
const val = 'hello world';
```

---

I'll offer a little example.  Suppose you have a function that returns some data from some other server and you have a simple cache.  The function should always return a promise because it may need to go get the data from another server (an asynchronous operation).  But, sometimes you will already have the data in the local cache.  You need your function to consistently return a promise so the caller has a nice clean and consistent API.

```
 const cache = new Map();
 const rp = require('request-promise');

 function getData(id) {
     // see if we already have the result in the cache
     if (cache.has(id)) {
         // if so, return a promise that is resolved with our cached value
         return Promise.resolve(cache.get(id));
     } else {
         return rp(myURL + "?id=" + id).then(data => {
             // cache the value
             cache.set(id, data);
             return data;
         });
     }     
 }
```

In this example, we specifically need to always return a promise for consistency of use of the function.  But, when we have the value in the cache, we want to return an already resolved promise that has our value in it.  So, we use `Promise.resolve()` specifically for that.

The caller can then consistently always use the returned promise without having to know anything about whether the value was cached or not:

```
 getData("price").then(val => {
     console.log(val);
 }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks jfriend, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what `await` does.  In a way, it can be thought of as "unwrapping" a Promise– semantically, you are waiting for the Promise to resolve and then getting the resolved value.  As a result, you can only use `await` within an asynchronous function (designated with the `async` keyword) which forces the return value of that function to itself be a Promise.

So, for example:

```
async function example() {
  return await promise;
}
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
function example() {
  return promise.then(result => {
   return result;
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Casey, that makes perfect sense.